# Substring Merge on a column with special characters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-re

I want to merge two dfs over 'Name' columns. However, one of them can be substring or exactly equal to other column. For this, I have used

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Name': ['12,5mg/0,333ml(37,5mg/ml)', 'ad', 'aaa'],
    }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Name': ['12,5mg/0,333ml(37,5mg/ml)', 'ad', 'aaaa'],
    }
)

str_match = "({})".format("|".join(df1.Name))
df2.merge(df1, 
          left_on=df2.Name.str.extract(str_match)[0], 
          right_on="Name", how='outer')
```

'ad', 'aaa', 'aaaa' values are merged correctly. However, the problem occurs on the value '12,5mg/0,333ml(37,5mg/ml)' (most probably because of special characters).
[What I got with this code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EVmk.png)

I have tried re.espace() but it did not help me. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: How did you use `re.escape`? It is the right tool to avoid the special characters. That said, it would be interesting to know the larger context and show some more corner cases. What is the desired behavior if there are multiple matches? Or if strings in `df1.Name` are substrings of one another? There might be a better way to get what you are _really_ looking for. As it is, the question feels a bit like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape any special character. I would also keep only distinct values of the escaped strings (to simplify the regex if there are many repeats) and compile the pattern beforehand:

```py
pattern = re.compile('({})'.format(
    '|'.join(pd.unique(df1.Name.apply(re.escape)))
))
out = df2.merge(
    df1, 
    left_on=df2.Name.str.extract(pattern)[0],
    right_on="Name", how='outer')

>>> out
  Name                       Name_x                     Name_y                    
0  12,5mg/0,333ml(37,5mg/ml)  12,5mg/0,333ml(37,5mg/ml)  12,5mg/0,333ml(37,5mg/ml)
1                         ad                         ad                         ad
2                        aaa                       aaaa                        aaa
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Doesn't creating cross product also take too long?

Comment: Good point. I removed the cross join idea. It would be interesting to know the larger context. There might be a better way to get what you are _really_ looking for. As it is, the question feels a bit like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is:

```
str_match = "({})".format("|".join(df1.Name))
df1.merge(df2['Name'], how='outer',
          left_on=df1['Name'].str.extract(str_match, expand=False)[0],
          right_on=df2['Name'].str.extract(str_match, expand=False)[0],
         ).drop(columns='key_0')
```

which gives:

```
                      Name_x                     Name_y
0  12,5mg/0,333ml(37,5mg/ml)  12,5mg/0,333ml(37,5mg/ml)
1                         ad                         ad
2                        aaa                       aaaa
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, this is not exactly what I want. These functions are not able to find substrings (finding 'aaa' inside 'aaaa')

Comment: If I create extra different rows such as 'adds' in df1 and 'dddddddd' in df2. I expect there should be extra 2 row in merged df, for each of them one column is NaN and the other column includes value. However with this function, it cannot achieve this.